# Serialize a field as a JSON object in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-queryset

(Django 1.8.5)
Suppose I want to print out the number of answers and distinct questions for each user.

---

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(db_column='Nickname', db_index=True, max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(db_column='Email', db_index=True, null=True)


class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='UserId')

class Answer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='QuestionId')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='UserId')
```

---

views.py:

```
from django.db.models import Count
stats = Answer.objects.values('user').annotate(number_of_answers=Count('id'), number_of_answered_questions=Count('question', distinct=True))
```

---

Now,

```
print(stats[0])
```

gives me

```
{'number_of_answered_questions': 4, 'number_of_answers': 5, 'user': 1}
```

However, I would like the output to look like this:

```
{'number_of_answered_questions': 4, 'number_of_answers': 5, 'user': {'id':1, 'nickname': 'my_nickname'}}
```

What should my serializer(e.g. UserStatSerializer) be?

Notes:
1) I will not use the serializer for deserialization.
2) I only want to know id & nickname. Other fields such as email(actually, there are other fields as well) should not be included in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact this is the default `values` behaviour. If you have a field called user that is a **ForeignKey**, the default `values()` call will return a dictionary key called user_id, since this is the name of the hidden model attribute that stores the actual value. When you are calling values() and passing in field names, you can pass in either `user` or `user_id` and you will get back the same thing and the dictionary key will match the field name you passed in.

You can do it manually:

```
for stat in stats:
     stat['user'] = User.objects.filter(id=stat['user']).values('id', 'nickname')
```

Check [Values() doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values) for more details.